# Is it possible to implement cosmetic rules like indentation and spacing in PMD using XPath?

Tags: java, eclipse, xpath, pmd

I did a detailed search for this on almost every link I found through google or YouTube but every where I was able to look for the examples implementing only the logical or programming rules instead of how to implement our own indentation rules.
Please help me out through this.

Answer (score 0):

PMD is used to find design flaws in your code. It is not possible to write cosmetic rules for PMD that check the formatting of your code.

[Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) is what your are looking for. It is built to keep the formatting of your code consistent. There is also the [Eclipse Checkstyle Plugin](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/) which runs Checkstyle in the background and marks formatting issues directly in the editor.